# Инструмент\ПО для централизованной установки ПО на армы под Windows 10?

Tags: windows, администрирование

Доброго времени суток!
Есть 20 АРМ под управлением windows 10 с oem ключом. На всех нужно запустить обновление ОС, установить одинаковые программы и раскинуть разные ip адреса.
Вытягивать ключи, делать образ с одного подготовленного АРМ и потом распихивать на все меняя ключ не очень хочется.
Рассматривал вариант с WPI, но опять же вариант для точечной установки. AD своего нет. ПО в большинстве случаев .exe, msi всего пару штук.
Прошу подсказать\надоумить как централизованно накатить ПО на эти АРМы. Какие инструменты использовать?
Вопрос задан час назад  40 просмотров

Comment: сделать ad неплохо бы

Comment: `Ansible` не? Или под виндой на arm нет winrm\powershell? Я просто не в курсе.

Comment: ну если без изучения детального API инсталляторов каждого пакета ПО, без изучения скритов или команд управления обновлением и пр., то можно использовать примитивные способы повторения действий с помощью (не примитивных!) программ автоматизации: [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/ru-ru/desktop/), [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) и пр.